# EIP not in known module, under WOW64

Tags: windows, windbg, amd64

I'm using WinDbg to debug a program under WOW64 (OS is x64, app is 32-bit).

I came across some indirect call inside the process module (module created by the app and not Windows), and started following it.

Stepping into this call gets me to an `(*)` address which doesn't match any loaded module:
Tried to search manually with `lm`, didn't see a match.
Used `!address` command with that address, and it says the page is committed but the protection is `PAGE_NOACCESS`.
Also the stack trace gives me a warning "frame ip not in any known module".

Stepping one more, I get again an indirect call to `fs[0c0h]` which is a stub for `WOW32Reserved` (after some more single stepping I get into `ntdll.dll`. So it's obviously some WOW64 code).

The question is, where did the code in `(*)` came from? Who's responsible for it? Why isn't it mapped to any module?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the process has allocated a page for itself, in which it has placed code to run.  It might be a form of obfuscation, or if the file was packed, then the unpacker code might be in that page.  If you're able to step into the code, then it can't be `PAGE_NOACCESS`, so perhaps the debugger is confused.  The call through `fs[0c0h]` is the interface for 32-bit code to call kernel code in a 64-bit environment.  Depending on the version of Windows, there is either a far jump at that location (pre-Win10), or some stack manipulation followed by a `retf` (Win10).

Comment: Well.. I hardly believe the debugger is confused, since it's WinDbg.